# Adding field to an object based on a conditional statement

Tags: typescript

I have an if statement upon which the fields of the object are updated. Obviously it works but I was wondering if there is a way of having more concise definition that would add or omit `a` field based on `xxx` condition?

```
// pseudo code
if(xxx) 
    data.update({b, c});
else
    data.update({a, b, c});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One liner I was looking for `data.update({b, c, ...(xxx && {a})});`

If xxx is truthy then spread operator will be executed on `{a}` and the resulting argument passed to the function will be equaled `{b, c, a}`

If xxx is falsy spread operator is executed on empty object `{}` and resulting argument will be equaled `{b, c}`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use

> Object.assign(target, source)

function.

Here is the code.

```
const t = { b, c };

if (xxx) {
    // do whatever you want.
} else {
    Object.assign(t, { a });
    // t is then { a, b, c }
}
```

Hope this helps you.